# cannot inject (@EJB) ejb using its superclass

Tags: ejb, cdi

I am learning both CDI and EJB. Looking at WELD's explanation of CDI (http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/beanscdi.html), it states that

> The unrestricted set of bean types for a session bean contains all local interfaces of the bean and their superinterfaces. If the session bean has a bean class local view, the unrestricted set of bean types contains the bean class and all superclasses. In addition, java.lang.Object is a bean type of every session bean. But remote interfaces are not included in the set of bean types.

I am trying to test this particular part

> the unrestricted set of bean types contains the bean class and all superclasses

So I have created two EJBs: ReferencedEJB which extends DummyParent and MainEJB which has a reference to EJB

DummyParent.java

```
package com.etm.ejbtest;

public abstract class DummyParent {
    public DummyParent() {
    }

    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }
}
```

ReferencedEJB.java

```
package com.etm.ejbtest;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;


@Singleton
@Startup
public class ReferencedEJB extends DummyParent  {
    public ReferencedEJB() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        System.out.println("init of ReferencedEJB");
    }
}
```

MainEJB.java

```
package com.etm.ejbtest;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class MainEJB {
    @EJB
    private DummyParent dummyParent;

    public MainEJB() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        System.out.println("init of MainEJB");
        dummyParent.sayHi();
    }
}
```

I am running this on JBoss 7 but I get an error saying

> No EJB found with interface of type 'com.etm.ejbtest.DummyParent' for binding com.etm.ejbtest.MainEJB/dummyParent

Any idea why it does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse CDI and the `@EJB` annotation; the `@EJB` injection is managed by the *EJB container*, not CDI; it will inject an EJB, and `DummyParent` is *not* an EJB.

This sounds counter-intuitive for someone new on the scene.  EJBs came along well before the official Java EE support for CDI.

A Google search for injecting EJBs via CDI may shed some light on this for you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, when I change it to "@Inject" instead of "@EJB" it does work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `@EJB(beanInterface=ReferencedEJB.class)` or `@EJB(beanName="ReferencedEJB")` so the EJB container knows which EJB you want.  As of EE 6/EJB 3.1, you could also use `EJB(lookup="...")` to specify the java:global, java:app, or java:module JNDI name of the target EJB.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to inject your EJB this way if you use the following lookup parameter:

```
 @EJB(lookup="{moduleName}/ReferencedEJB")
 private DummyParent parent;
```